# Comparing Associative array and standard array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays

Array1:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 1 [2] => 4 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 6 ) )
```

Array2:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 2 )
```

I used `array_diff` for comparing and getting the difference values, but the same key is coming ie.,

```
array_diff(Array1,Array2)
```

returns `Array([0] =>3 [2] => 4)`

but is there any other way to get difference and having result like

`Array([0] =>3 [1] => 4)..`

Comment: You need to clarify a bit. What result are you expecting / do you want?

Comment: Any other method other than array_diff()(because it returns result along with key) for getting difference between two arrays..I want result as Array([0] =>3 [1] => 4) instead of Array([0] =>3 [2] => 4)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've got array_diff working on the multidimensional array somehow, but from the docs:

> This function only checks one dimension of a n-dimensional array. Of course you can check deeper dimensions by using array_diff($array1[0], $array2[0]);.

Use array_values around it.

```
array_values(array_diff($array1, $array2));
```